Rigify hands and feet generating in the default (rest) position
Had this issue on the file I was working on so I tried creating a new empty blend file where only a metarig was added, after generating the rig I got the same problem - the controller for the feet and the hands appear in the default (rest) position, everything else works fine.
Again, completely empty blend file with only the metarig and the rig. Not sure what could be causing this.


Hi. What Blender version is this? Have you placed the armature in front view at the world origin? I've just tried in Blender 4.2.1. It works for both the basic and normal human metarig (https://i.sstatic.net/IxRIswrW.jpg). I have no idea what causes this.

Please upload your file, so we can check.

here's the blend file, sorry! https://gofile.io/d/S06T0o  --  yes, i'm using version 4.2.1.

Hey, thanks for the file. Now it's clear what the problem is. You made the changes for the metarig in Pose mode, but you should have made them in Edit mode. Because you need to change the rest pose of the metarig and not create new a pose. -- To fix the problem, switch to Pose mode in which you accidentally made the changes and apply this pose as a new rest pose via the menu item Pose > Apply > Apply Pose as Rest Pose. Now you will have the same bone layout in Edit mode and the rig creation will work fine.
